# Random circles being detected

Tags: random, opencv, computer-vision, detection, geometry

I'm trying to detect circles but I am detecting circles that aren't even there. My code is below. Anyone know how to modify the DetectCircle() method to make the detection more accurate , please and thanks

```
void detectCircle( IplImage * img )
{
    int edge_thresh = 1;
    IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width,img->height), 8, 1);
    IplImage *edge = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width,img->height), 8, 1);

    cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    gray->origin = 1;

    // color threshold
    cvThreshold(gray,gray,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);    

    // smooths out image
    cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11);

    // get edges
    cvCanny(gray, edge, (float)edge_thresh, (float)edge_thresh*3, 5); 

    // detects circle
    CvSeq* circle =  cvHoughCircles(edge, cstorage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
        edge->height/50, 5, 35);

    // draws circle and its centerpoint
    float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circle, 0 );
    if( p==null ){ return;}

    cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 3, CV_RGB(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(200,0,0), 1, 8, 0 );

    cvShowImage ("Snooker", img );
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `cvCanny` if you don't use the `edge` result afterwards?

Comment: yes that was a mistake. have that changed but still getting circles detected randomly

Comment: After the smoothing try another Threshold with 127.

Comment: And if you want more than poking in the dark, you should really post example images, images of the intermediate steps (smoothing, canny), and the output you get and expect.

Comment: What would another threshold of 127 do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvHoughCircles detects circles that arent obvious to us.  If you know the pixel size of snooker balls you can filter them based on their radius. Try setting the min_radius and max_radius parameters in your cvHoughCircles function.

On a side note, once you get the circles, you can filter them based on color.  If the circle is mostly one color, it has a good chance of being a ball, if it doenst its probably a false positive.

edit: by "circle's color" i mean the pixels inside the circle boundary

Comment: I'll give this a go. Thanks for the advise. Ya, i'm just working on getting the 22 balls detected and then il be heading on to the color. Thanks again